# Why am I getting 'missing terminating " character'?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

```
// Example 1
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("hello World"
  );
}

// Example 2
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("hello World
  ");
}
```

In example 1, the compiler did not show any error, but in example 2, it shows a `missing terminating " character` error. Why?

Comment: In _exapmle2_ compiler is unable to locate ending `"` in the same line while in _example1_ it does.

Comment: you might want to use like `printf("hello World"   
        "second line");`

Comment: This ***must*** be a duplicate.

Comment: A starting point: *[Why must C/C++ string literal declarations be single-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093632/why-must-c-c-string-literal-declarations-be-single-line)* (2010)

Answer (score 9):

C string literals can not contain literal linefeeds. Here's the [C18](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) standard with the relevant part highlighted.

> 6.4.5 String literals
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> string-literal:
>    encoding-prefixopt " s-char-sequenceopt "
>
> s-char-sequence:
>   s-char
>   s-char-sequence s-char
>
> s-char:
>   any member of the source character set except
>     the double-quote ", backslash \, or new-line character  <---- HERE
>   escape-sequence
> ```

If you want your string literal to contain a linefeed, use `\n` instead, e.g. `"hello\nworld"`.

If you want your string literal to be broken across multiple lines, use multiple string literals:

```
printf("hello "
       "world");
```

Comment: Sir in your example how will compiler deal with statement if it did not find semicolon in first line?

Comment: You can have linefeeds almost anywhere between tokens, just not inside string literals. The compiler will just keep reading lines until it finds the `;`.